# Laravel-blade-@extends no funciona y falta snippet?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un problema con @extends, no se activa, se queda en blanco cuando realizo la solicitud de la ruta:

```
Route::get('/demos', function () {
    return view('demo');
});
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> (2/2) ErrorException Cannot end a section without first starting
>   one.(View: C:\wamp64\www\gestiondatos\resources\views\demo.blade.php)

Me han dicho que es por los snippet, pero no se como activarlo.

adjunto la imagen, como se ve que están en blanco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en la línea 7.

Cuando pasamos **2 parametros** a `@section` blade se encarga de autocerrar la sección, por lo que **no debemos incluir la etiqueta `@endsection`** para dicha sección.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('titulo', 'Mi titulo')// se cierra @section automáticamente

// Esta etiqueta @endsection sobra
@endsection

@section('content')
    Hola mundo!

// Aquí si se debe cerrar
@endsection
```

Aun que pasar parametros al `@endsection` no genera ningún error, carece de sentido, ya que no admite ningún parámetro.

Por lo tanto tu código podría quedar algo así:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('titulo', 'Mi titulo')

@section('content')
    Contenido de la sección 
@endsection
```

Comment: Hola Xerif,  Me ha funcionado correctamente, todo el tiempo pensaba que era porque no se ponía en color cuando usaba los parámetros, pero al quitar la línea 7.  perfecto,Ya he aprendido una cosa mas. Muchas gracias, sigo con la duda el porque no cambia de color, es blanco, por eso envié la imagen y no el código en texto, seguimos adelante. gracias

Comment: Hola Xerif, gracias por tu ayuda, la verdad que he dedicado horas, con gusto claro,

Comment: Hola Xerif, gracias por todo, me esta siendo de gran ayuda para poder seguir en mi formación, muy agradecido la verdad. he descargado el archivo, según como venia, pero igual, salgo y entro, pero @extends, sigue en blanco. Pero las etiquetas si cambian de color solo cuando pongo @..., por que es?, un saludo